# Document metadata properties in sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, openxml-sdk

Facing issue with metadata property values which are edited in word document.
If they are edited from word document and uploaded to sharepoint library, it works as expected and sharepoint library displays data.

Requirement is. I am trying edit property values using open xml sdk.

The values can be manually seen by changing document extension from ".docm" to ".zip" and extrating the data and looking at docprops->custom.xml

TIll this point it is as expected.

When this is uploaded to sharepoint library , the values are not recognized and hence are removed from the xml and are not displayed in library.(NO error is shown).only Metadata values are not displayed.

This is quite tricky.Any help would be great..